# When does the Steinberg representation fail to be irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

It is not clear to me when the Steinberg representation of an arbitrary finite classical group should be irreducible. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinberg_representation#The_Steinberg_representation_of_a_finite_group) seems to claim that it is for all finite groups. Is this true? How might I prove this/where can I find a proof of this?

It seems probable that one of the sources of [Curtis's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869366900330) paper might provide details, but I can't access a number of these currently, and those which I've checked haven't made things clearer.

The particular case I care about is the symplectic group $\text{Sp}_4(2^r)$, being $4\times 4$ symplectic matrices with entries from a finite field of $2^r$ elements, but I'd like to understand this better in general.